# How to make a checkbox be checked and div hidden when page loads?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a checkbox. I have a div with content under the checkbox. When the checkbox is checked, the div is hidden. When the checkbox is unchecked, the div is visible.

When the page is loaded, I want the checkbox to be checked and the div to already be hidden. When the checkbox is unchecked, the div should be visible.

I have tried using the click function, and I’ve tried using show and hide. But I can’t get the code to do what I want. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#checkbox_content').change(function()
    {
        if(this.checked)
            $('#content').fadeOut('slow');
        else
            $('#content').fadeIn('slow');       
    });
});
</script>


<div>
    <form action="">
       <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="checkbox_content" checked="checked">
    </form>
</div>


<div id="content"> 
    div content here 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `display:none` to your div:

```
<div id="content" style="display:none;"> 
    div content here 
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2mt1q6rq/)

The div will now be hidden by default, the rest of your code will do what you want without any change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle to your query.

https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/L8eyrmjs/

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#checkbox_content').change(function()
    {
        if(this.checked)
            $('#content').fadeOut('slow');
        else
            $('#content').fadeIn('slow');       
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <form action="">
       <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="checkbox_content" checked="checked">
    </form>
</div>


<div id="content" class="displayNone"> 
    div content here 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.displayNone{display:none;}
```

Hope this helps. Basically you just need to hide the div at the start as you are making the checkbox as checked using the property "checked". 
Tip: It is better to maintain CSS in a separate css file rather than writing it inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="checkbox_content" checked="checked" onChange="$('#content').fadeToggle('slow');">
</form>
<div id="content" style="display:none">
  div content here
</div>
```

It seems you are using jQuery.